# Send a private messege to everyone that has a role in discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to send a private message to everyone in a discord channel if they have a certain role.

I manage to find this :

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

TOKEN = 'xxx'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def message_role(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, message):
    for member in ctx.message.server.members:
        if role in member.roles:
            await bot.send_message(member, message)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I use Client.x but I don't understand what Bot. is and when I run this, I get the following error message:

```
PS D:\discord bots> py .\DMeveryone.py
Ignoring exception in command message_role:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 898, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 608, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 573, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 491, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 353, in transform
    return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 308, in do_conversion
    return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 254, in _actual_conversion
    ret = await instance.convert(ctx, argument)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 320, in convert
    raise NoPrivateMessage()
discord.ext.commands.errors.NoPrivateMessage
```

this is the messege : !message_role member Hi everybody!

If someone can explain to me the problem that would be awesome, thank you very much.

Comment: From what I can see you are getting `exception discord.ext.commands.NoPrivateMessage(message=None, *args)` which is essentially telling you -> Exception raised when an operation does not work in private message contexts

Comment: so this can't work?

Comment: It works if you call the command from a text channel in a server the bot is on but not from a Private Message

Comment: @Tristo I already tried that. I get an error aswell : discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'server'

Comment: @lucky_dandu That's an error in code that's not posted here, but it means somewhere you're doing `message.server` when you need to do `message.channel.server` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[discord.ext.commands.Bot](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#bot) is part of the commands extension of discord.py and subclasses discord.Client.

Per the documentation for [discord.ext.commands.NoPrivateMessage](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.NoPrivateMessage), it's

> raised when an operation does not work in private message contexts.

This is because you're attempting to use a command that uses a [RoleConverter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.RoleConverter) through DMs, where there are no roles.

The reason you're getting an `AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'server'` exception is because you're attempting to use the [Message.server](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.server) attribute, but you're using the rewrite branch of discord.py, where [Server is now Guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#server-is-now-guild).
Message.server exists as a shortcut attribute for Message.channel and Channel.server on the async branch of discord.py ([@Patrick Haugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6779307/patrick-haugh)). Correspondingly, [Message.guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Message.guild) exists as an attribute on the rewrite branch.

You're also using a method to send messages that only exists on the async branch.
See the [Sending Messages subsection of the Migrating to v1.0 section of the documentation for the rewrite branch](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#migrating-1-0-sending-messages).

Also, [`pass_context=True` no longer exists and is no longer necessary on the rewrite branch](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#context-changes).

Comment: Are  you sure they're using rewrite?  They have `await bot.send_message` in the code above.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yes, I pointed that out.
`raise NoPrivateMessage()` is currently on [line 320 of discord/ext/commands/converter.py on the rewrite branch](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/discord/ext/commands/converter.py#L320), as in the traceback for the exception.
Whereas, [discord/ext/commands/converter.py on the async branch](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/converter.py) doesn't even have 320 lines.

Comment: It's on line 151 instead https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/converter.py#L151

Comment: Yes, and at no point was it at line 320 on the async branch, where their exception traceback shows it at.